# Best way to geocode Ukraine postcode with Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

What is the most effective and accurate way to geocode a Ukraine postcode? Using the built in geocode object results in massively blurred results (lots of postcodes returning just a general area).

Are there any free Ukraine postcode geocoding services I can plug into via JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I´ve understand your Question correct, you could simply set a `componentRestrictions`. Could look like this:

```
doGeocode: function (address, postal_code, callback) {
    console.log("TEST: " + address.toString());
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address,
        'componentRestrictions': {
            'postalCode': postal_code,
            'country': 'de' //change this to the Code of Ukraine 
        }
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            console.log(results);
            callback(results);
        } else {
            //Error handling
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
```

> Note: Of course you have to set the country code for Ukraine here. And, because you didn´t mentioned which information you have either address or lat/lng, I just gave you an example for addresses.